# How do I paste richtext into a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I want to highlight some stuff on a web page and be able to paste it into a richtextbox in C# winforms. I want to then be able to see the HTML code of what I had pasted.  Is this possible?

Comment: I assume you want to automate this from some code, and not just use built in Windows functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet will return a string containing the code.  There is some header info at the top that you may want to parse out but it is pretty straight forward.

```
string html = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html).ToString();
```

You will be able to populate that into a text box or richtext box however you like.